# Convert vertical data to horizontal in Excel 365

Tags: excel

I have the following data

```
1   Product name    Component1  1
                    Component2  1
                    Component3  1
2   Product name    Component1  1
                    Component2  1
```

I have to convert it to the following

```
1   Product name    Component1  1 Component2  1  Component3 1
2   Product name    Component1  1 Component2  1
```

Components should also be in alphabetical order.

Is there any method to do that in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried with [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, you need to program it using VBA.